# Rollback parent procedure on failure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transaction, rollback

I have the following two procedures on my server:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`someone`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `NewMagnet`(
    IN `nick` VARCHAR(32), 
    IN `tth` CHAR(39), 
    IN `name` TINYTEXT, 
    IN `size` BIGINT, 
    IN `eid` INT, 
    OUT `maid` INT
)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Automated insertion to magnets and filename tables'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO magnets (eid, tth, size, nick, date)
    SELECT
        eid,
        tth,
        size,
        m.id,
        NOW()
    FROM modtable m
    WHERE m.nick = nick;
    SET maid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO filenames
    VALUES( LAST_INSERT_ID(), name );
END
```

This procedure is called from inside of another procedure named `NewEntry`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`someone`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `NewEntry`(
    IN `ctg` VARCHAR(15), 
    IN `msg` TINYTEXT, 
    IN `nick` VARCHAR(32), 
    IN `tth` CHAR(39), 
    IN `name` TINYTEXT, 
    IN `size` BIGINT, 
    OUT `eid` INT, 
    OUT `maid` INT
)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Automated procedure to insert a new entry'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO entries (msg, nick, date, ctg)
    SELECT
        msg,
        m.id,
        NOW(),
        c.id
    FROM modtable m, ctgtable c
    WHERE c.name = ctg
        AND m.nick = nick
    LIMIT 1;
    SET eid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    CALL NewMagnet( nick, tth, name, size, eid, maid );
END
```

I want the `NewEntry` procedure to rollback itself if the call to `NewMagnet` fails. Currently, what happens is that a new entry is added to the `entries` table even if the `magnets` table `INSERT` query failed for any reason (duplicate key, mostly).

I've read [this thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20046066/1190388) ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/20046066/1190388 ) for creating a handler in a procedure, but I am unaware about how to implement it for the parent procedure `NewEntry` in my case.

---

## EDIT

Based on the thread linked above; I updated my procedures to the following:

#### NewEntry

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE exit handler for SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    DECLARE exit handler for SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO entries (msg, nick, date, ctg)
    SELECT
        msg,
        m.id,
        NOW(),
        c.id
    FROM modtable m, ctgtable c
    WHERE c.name = ctg
        AND m.nick = nick
    LIMIT 1;
    SET eid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    CALL NewMagnet( nick, tth, name, size, eid, maid );
    COMMIT;
END
```

#### NewMagnet

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
        BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO magnets (eid, tth, size, nick, date)
    SELECT
        eid,
        tth,
        size,
        m.id,
        NOW()
    FROM modtable m
    WHERE m.nick = nick;
    SET maid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO filenames
    VALUES( LAST_INSERT_ID(), name );
    COMMIT;
END
```

But it is still inserting a new row to the `entries` table even when the duplicate key exists for the `magnets` values passed.

---

## EDIT

To explain what is happening and to clear [some doubts Anup has](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62147/rollback-parent-procedure-on-failure-in-mysql#comment111810_62147); I created two new tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `b` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`b`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    `id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `f` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

And then created two new procedures as well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `s`(IN `f` TINYINT, OUT `z` TINYINT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'dsf'
BEGIN
    DECLARE exit HANDLER
    FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
            SET z = -1;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO a
    VALUES( f );
    SET z = f;
    COMMIT;
END
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `t`(IN `r` TINYINT, OUT `l` TINYINT, OUT `z` TINYINT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE exit HANDLER
    FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
            SET l = -1;
            SET z = -1;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO b (f)
    VALUES( r );
    SET l = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    CALL s( r, z );
    COMMIT;
END
```

Then, I executed following commands:

```
CALL s(3, @z);
SELECT @z;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 0.046 sec. */
```

This inserted the value `3` in my table `a`. `z` was returned as `3` correctly. Next, I executed:

```
CALL s(3, @z);
SELECT @z;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 1  Duration for 2 queries: 0.000 sec. */
```

And the warning led to the rollback and I received `z` as `-1`. So far so good.

Now, I executed following statements:

```
CALL t(3, @l, @z);
SELECT @l, @z;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 1  Duration for 2 queries: 0.015 sec. */
CALL t(3, @l, @z);
SELECT @l, @z;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 1  Duration for 2 queries: 0.016 sec. */
CALL t(3, @l, @z);
SELECT @l, @z;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 1  Duration for 2 queries: 0.000 sec. */
```

And the value for `z` was returned always as `-1` but the value of `l` was incremented every time. So, now I have the table `b` like in the picture below:

[image: my table <code>b</code>]

Which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: you got the right link. Did you try as the link explained how to implement Transactions? what you missing is "you will have to put all your code inside transaction." In your case "CALL NewMagnet( nick, tth, name, size, eid, maid );" should also fall inside START Transaction - COMMIT" block.

Comment: @AnupShah Check my edits above.

Comment: sorry to say but you could have done little better in searching the answer for same question. on SO only i found multiple instances of this question. here are some useful links where user has accepted the answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827036/mysql-nested-transaction-with-rollback http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076566/how-to-detect-a-rollback-in-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: if this question was in other forum this would be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @AnupShah Please read up again! I guess that makes my question unique enough?

Comment: in the procedure "t" COMMIT or ROLLBACK should be done based on the value of output parameter z from CALL "s". if the value of z is -1 then you should do ROLLBACK and set l=-1 but if value of z is not -1 then COMMIT and you already have value of l set properly.

Comment: try the updated proc and let us know.

Comment: Have you tried using [XA TRANSATCIONS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html) instead of *normal* transactions?

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `t`(IN `r` TINYINT, OUT `l` TINYINT, OUT `z` TINYINT)
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT ''
    BEGIN
        DECLARE exit HANDLER
        FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
            BEGIN
                SET l = -1;
                SET z = -1;
                ROLLBACK;
            END;
        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO b (f)
        VALUES( r );
        SET l = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        CALL s( r, z );
        IF z==-1 
        THEN
          ROLLBACK;
        ELSE
          COMMIT;
        END IF;
    END
```

**EDIT:1**

here is the demo 
[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94971/8)

inner procedure also has transaction and that is doing all previous DML COMMIT.
If you move your Insert after the CALL in outer procedure you will there is no insert. 
but it may not always possible to change order. somehow we have to avoid the COMMIT from any nested procedure call and do only in the parent procedure.

but sometime those nested procedures can be called independently and you may want to keep Transactions for those calls. so basically what I am doing is adding Transaction/Rollback/Commit statement based on the parameter passed to the procedure.

when making a call directly from APP Code to procedure always pass 1 and hence the procedure will be use explicit Transaction. but when you making nested call in parent procedure you do not want to use transaction for nested calls so explicitly pass 0.

```
    CREATE TABLE `a` (
          `b` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
          PRIMARY KEY (`b`)
    );
    CREATE TABLE `b` (
          `id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `f` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

    CREATE PROCEDURE `s`
    (
        IN `f` TINYINT,
        IN `NestedTran` TINYINT,
        OUT `z` TINYINT
    )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE exit HANDLER
        FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
            BEGIN
                SET z = -1;
                IF NestedTran = 1 THEN
                  ROLLBACK;
                END IF;
            END;
        IF NestedTran = 1 THEN
          START TRANSACTION;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO a
        VALUES( f );
        SET z = f;
    IF NestedTran = 1 THEN
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE `t`
    (
        IN `r` TINYINT,
        IN `NestedTran` TINYINT,
        OUT `l` TINYINT,
        OUT `z` TINYINT
    )
    BEGIN

        DECLARE exit HANDLER
        FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
            BEGIN
                SET l = -1;
                IF NestedTran = 1 THEN
                  ROLLBACK;
                END IF;
            END;
        IF NestedTran = 1 THEN
          START TRANSACTION;
        END IF;

          INSERT INTO b (f)
          VALUES( r );
          SET l = LAST_INSERT_ID();

          CALL s( r,0, z );

        IF z = -1 THEN
          IF NestedTran = 1 THEN
            ROLLBACK;
          END IF;
        ELSE
          IF NestedTran = 1 THEN
            COMMIT;
          END IF;
        END IF;

    END/
```

Comment: Never mind, I was using `SELECT maid = -1` instead of `SET`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029729/mysql-error-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: This method is working for my newer tables `a` and `b`. But it still doesn't rollback for `NewEntry`. My current procedures are [here](http://www.hastebin.com/sisaseqara.sql).

Comment: No, it isn't working for `a` and `b` either. I forgot to refresh the columns. You can see it [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eqGW4.jpg)

Comment: You can also see this behaviour on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbe3ed/1)

Comment: check the EDIT. This is happening due to COMMIT behavior. I am not able to fully resolve How to change that but has work around posted as answer.